# Hello World in APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

Not exacly World but it seems to be a simple task as well .

I am implemented LDAP authentication in APEX so after logon I would like to create Label on the top of form "Hello %LDAP_USER%".

Due to not understanding/misunderstanding  I ask the question again in other way:  How to create a text with current logged user.

Comment: -4 points in 1 hour, any explanation ?? someone can explain me why ?   easy to click "minus" more difficult to explain why :\

Comment: I do not know much about LDAP Authentication in APEX, but you probably need an application variable for that if you cannot use the predefined variable `APP_USER`. Note also that the syntax to include substitution strings is another one, it should look like this: `"Hello &LDAP_USER."` If you do not know the syntax for substitution strings, then it is hard to imagine how we may able to help you with much more complicated things, like extracting environment variables in your case.

Answer (score 0):

&APP_USER. should work just fine, independently of how the user was authenticated.

Comment: Your probably being down-voted because you used the "apex" tag and not the "oracle-apex" tabg

Comment: well instead of **&** I used **:** and now it works. Anyway it probably depends on context .   I found a page which helped me a lot : [http://warp11.nl/2011/04/apex-built-in-variables](http://warp11.nl/2011/04/apex-built-in-variables/)